# How can I navigate activity to fragment via backbutton (arrow)?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have tried

```
YourFragment mapFragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.landlord_apartment, mapFragment, mapFragment.getTag()).commit();
```

But my acivity overlapped to my fragment?
How can I solve that?
I want to back via action bar arrow button

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution if you back to fragment from fragment

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, yourFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but from activity to fragment just add

```
 finish();
```

Comment: I want to navigate from activity to another activity's fragment
How can I do that? Thanks